# Google Maps APIv2 - Map does not load

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I was using the previous Maps API - after inserting the following code snippet for the Maps v2 API, the map does not load. The CustomMapView is a Java class which inherits the MapView. Cant understand what all parameters should be replaced or removed?

```
<com.stub.android.ui.CustomMapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Ive added the following in the Manifest -

```
  <permission
    android:name="com.stub.android.ui.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.stub.android.ui.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Code for the CustomMapView class

```
public class CustomMapView extends MapView {

public CustomMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
    super(context, apiKey);
    // this.context = context;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        int zoomLevel = getZoomLevel();
        getController().setZoom(zoomLevel-1);
        super.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    try {
        super.draw(canvas);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        int zoomLevel = getZoomLevel();
        getController().setZoom(zoomLevel-1);
        super.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // this.context = context;
}

public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);


}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    System.gc();
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.towntour.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.temp.android.maps.googlev2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission  android:name="com.temp.android.maps.googlev2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDp6PHK3NYNwS74cKGmX-xc4LuH_uM1mIo" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.temp.android.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i wanna understand the changes to made in the XML layout and not the manifest

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: how can i incorporate the same, in the existing xml layout, mentioned above in the question, am including the java mapview class in the layout,

Comment: just set this xml in your existing xml code...and run it..it will work properly...

Comment: your not getting me, in that case what should be done for the MapView java class?

Comment: Okey now i got your point...First right Click On your Project select The property-->select the Android -->Check The Google Api -->Ok-->Now Implement Your Activity As Map Activity...it will work .....properly..

Answer (score 0):

```
This Way will be usefull for that..


public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="API_KEY"
/>

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: how i can use the HelloGoogleMaps class in the XML layout, as i did in my code above for APIv2 - <com.stub.android.ui.CustomMapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

Comment: its activity you can't use it..HelloGoogleMaps...For map class will came from its library..u can't do like that sir..........

Comment: ive been using this code http://pastebin.com/87qY2hj1 this is a custom class that extends MapView which i include via package name in my layout, coz that is a reusable component

Comment: i cant do that, this is client proprietary project! we can speak over screen share skype?